# jstree - one tree in different pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

i have a short question for the jstree (jstree.com)

I would use one instance of the tree in different pages an save the current tree status with the "stage property"

For example. I have the follow pages which have there own content.

index.htm
  example1.htm
  example2.htm
impressum.htm

Now i would build the navigation with the jstree. When i click at a link the called page open and i can use the "same" jstree instance. But i will not define a new tree in each site. Is this possible?

Thank you

Felix

Comment: Why don't you try it?

Comment: Fine it is possible ;) . Thats good. But how is it possible? How can i use the existing instance at a new browser page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move all common code to a script file and include it on each of the pages. Also make sure you enable the `state` plugin (in your jstree config) as it will persist opened/selected nodes across reloads.